# JSON: How to write the time in JSON

Tags: json

I try to compile this JSON string online but I think it grouses bout the time format, how can I write the time for parsing purpose?

```
{
    "1_hkmh": {
        "stops_name": "xyz",
        "arrival_time": {
            "mon-fri": [
                05:38,
                06:07,
                06:37
            ]
        },
        "stops_lat": 53.637994,
        "stops_long": 10.000423
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The times need to be quoted as strings: `["05:38", "06:07", "06:37"]`. How are you creating the JSON string?

Comment: @cmbuckley: I created it alone. it works now

Comment: @MrAsker Good, but depending on what language you're using, there is probably a JSON encoding function/library that could help you with building it and avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your time with double quotation marks.

```
{
    "1_hkmh": {
        "stops_name": "xyz",
        "arrival_time": {
            "mon-fri": [
                "05:38",
                "06:07",
                "06:37"
            ]
        },
        "stops_lat": 53.637994,
        "stops_long": 10.000423
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`05:38` is a literal that cannot be parsed by the JavaScript engine. You should work with strings in your JSON and parse them later into [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) objects.

**Example:**

```
{
"1_hkmh": {
    "stops_name": "xyz",
    "arrival_time": {
        "mon-fri": [
            "05:38",
            "06:07",
            "06:37"
        ]
    },
    "stops_lat": 53.637994,
    "stops_long": 10.000423
}
```